# 95% Confidence Interval Confusion

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, confidence-interval

I decided on an arbitrary bound to determine how large my sample size should be.  (There's a formula you can plug in "B" and find how big your sample size should be-size n).  I then calculated the estimated pop mean and its variance for the sample sized n.  If I do the estimated pop mean+/- 2*sqrt(var) would that be a 95% confidence interval?  Or no because I set a bound to determine my sample size?  Where does the bound I set come into play?  I'm a little confused.

Comment: This is a little bit confusing. The bound on your sample size should only affect the variance, by making it smaller for larger N. Something like $var=\sigma^2/{N}$. Why have you done $\pm 2\sqrt{var}$? If you did $1.96$ instead, IIRC that is the $z$ value for a $95\%$ confidence interval. I suppose you are close enough, but if you use $2$, your interval will be slightly less than $95\%$

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the response!  We learned in class to do +/2sqrt(var) for a 95% confidence interval-I know typically 1.96 is used.  Anyways I was just confused about the bound for the sample size but you have clarified that for me.

Comment: Ok great, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some basic facts about confidence intervals based on normal samples
will help you clarify how to proceed.

Suppose you have a random sample $X_i$ of size $n$ from a normal population with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma.$ Also suppose that $\mu$ is unknown and to be estimated by the sample mean $\bar X.$ And that $\sigma$ is known. Then usual 95% CI for $\mu$ is of the form $\bar X \pm 1.96 \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$

The usual terminology is that the 'standard error' is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$
That is, $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n$ and $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$
Also, the 'margin of error' is $1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n},$ which is half the
length of the CI.

If you want to balance the sample size $n$ against the margin of error $M$, this
means that the key equation is $M = 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n},$ which can solved
to express $n$ in terms of a desired $M$ and the constant $\sigma.$

If the sample standard deviation $\sigma$ is unknown and estimated by
the sample standard deviation $S,$ then the formula for the CI is
$\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n}.$ This makes it a little more complicated to find
$n$ in terms of $M$ and $\sigma$ because
the 'probability factor' $t^*$ is chosen to cut 2.5% of the area from
the upper tail of the (symmetrical) Student t distribution with $n-1$ degrees
of freedom.

One complication is that $t^*$ also depends on $n.$
But you can start with $t^* \approx 2$ and iterate, if $n$ is small enough
to give $t^*$ much larger than 2. Another complication is that $S$ is a
random variable and will typically be different from one sample to the next.
Thus, even if the exact value of $\sigma$ is unknown, it helps to have
some idea of its size.